# map_at with just a starting string "Exampl"

Tags: r, string, purrr, forecast

I have a list with multiple groupings of variables created by `aggregate()` from the package `hts`. I want to map a specific forecasting function depending on the name of the group.

Example of names:

```
G3/GRSA_
G3/COAR_
G4/COAR_RURA_
...
```

Basically I want something like

```
map(list, contains*("COAR"), forecast)
```

to forecast both `G3/COAR_` and `G4/COAR_RURA_`

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But consider to use `grep()`.

Comment: I think you could be interesting in `map_if` that apply a function on list element based on a predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spread the problem

names_to_map <- names(example_list)
grsa_names <- names_to_map [str_detect(names_to_map , "GRSA")]

map_at(example_list,names_to_map,example_function)